# Visualizar posicion de la página con dots

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de hacer que a medida que vaya haciendo scroll, detecte en qué posición de la página estoy, calculando qué section corresponde a dicha posición y se active el div correspondiente a dicha posición.

Inserto una imagen gráfica, ya que conozco mi pésima forma de explicarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento esto es lo que llevo:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    const dots      = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
    const sections  = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
    const body      = document.querySelector('body');

    setActive(0);
    
    function setActive(i){    
        for(dot of dots)
        dot.classList.remove('active');
        dots[i].classList.add('active');
    }
    
    for(let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
        dots[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            setActive(i);
        });
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        console.log(window.scrollY);


        for(let i = 0; i < sections.length - 1; i++){

            let rect = sections[i].getBoundingClientRect();
            let roct = sections[i+1].getBoundingClientRect();

            if(rect.top >= this.window.scrollY && roct.top <= this.window.scrollY){
                console.log('pasa');
                setActive(i);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

He probado ya de varias maneras, pero hasta ahora lo más lógico que he encontrado es esto, y no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antebrazo.

Answer (score 0):

Nada, ya lo resolví, cambiando la función del final, quitando el getBoundingRect() y sustituyéndolo por offsetTop valía.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){

        for(let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
            let top = sections[i].offsetTop;

            if(this.window.scrollY >= top){
                setActive(i);
            }
        }
    });
```